# Indexing into a multidimensional array with an array of indices

Tags: python

I want to index into a multidimensional array X of shape (32,6) with an index array I of shape (32,1) in order.
The for loop goes like this:

```
for b in range(32):
    output[b] = X[b, I[b]]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Is there an issue with the current code, or are you just looking for a simplification/improvement?

Comment: Simplification.

Answer (score 0):

A way this can be improved is by using a mix of list comprehension, and replacing the range with an `enumerate`, accessing the variable `I` only once. I am uncertain if it will provide any speed increase but I suspect there should be, since the function `range(32)` is skipped entirely, but in terms of simplification, I think this code is more straight-forward looking.

```
output = [X[index, value] for index, value in enumerate(I)]
```